# Snapshot of a LXC container

Tags: lxc

Please, is it possible to migrate a container to a new node and restart it there ? 
And How? should i take a snapshot of the container or i transfer the repository to the new node ?

(Beginner with LXC container)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a standard container under /var/lib/lxc, i.e. /var/lib/lxc/container1, then it suffices to stop the container, make sure lxc is set up on the new node (call it 'desthost') and

```
rsync -va /var/lib/lxc/container1 desthost:/var/lib/lxc/
```

(You can't yet migrate a running container;  hopefully that'll work "soon" using criu)